# Rails 4 send a mail with BCC

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I sent a mail with bcc in rails 4 but it is not working for me.How can i send it and also i tried pass an array of email to bcc.

```
default from: "test1@mail.com"
mail(to: "sample@mail.com",reply_to: "test@mail.com",
      bcc: "test1@mail.com",  subject: "sample subject")
```

Comment: it working in localhost letter opener but not working on production server.I sent a mail from production server.Bcc not display in mail.

Comment: You shouldn't see the BCC in the received email. The point is that it's _Blind_ Carbon Copy.

Comment: Thanks,it work fine.i didn't check it properly but bcc show when i sent a mail with bcc to my friend in gmail.